# Dynamically set Access-Allow-Control-Origin

Tags: javascript, django, same-origin-policy

I've read about getting around the same origin policy when sending POST requests [here](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript) and feel like I have a decent understanding of how the dynamic works.  Modern browsers support it by setting Access-Allow-Control-Origin on the receiving server, and all browsers work by submitting the request through an iframe.

My question is two fold:

1. Is there a way to dynamically set the origin allowed so that you don't have to set `Access-Allow-Control-Origin: *`.  More precisely is there a way to do it with a particular view or set of views in django. ( I know there is [this gist](https://gist.github.com/426829) which is usable as a middleware, but there doesn't seem to be a way to set the origin you are allowing on the fly.
2. Is there a wrapper you can use that has the deprecation built in? In other words it will try to use Access-Allow-Control-Origin and if
   the browser doesn't support it it will use an iframe instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite the middleware as a decorator.  This would actually be a better approach than the middleware in general I think since it would allow you to pass arguments to each usage of the decorator to customize the allowed methods.